# Grid being populated with all the record during paging

Tags: extjs4

The following is the code out of my js file...The problem which I am having is that grid is being populated with all the data and paging is not being implemented.

The paging par with number of pages and proper numbering comes up but at the same time all the data too...plz help

```
 Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.QuickTips.init();

//defining  model 
Ext.define('User1', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'fullName']
});

 //defining store

var registerBaby = Ext.create ( 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',{
    model: 'User1',
    autoLoad: true,      // autoload have been implemented  
    pageSize: 4,        
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'ActionServlet?id=gridPaging',   //points to a controller servlet
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }       
});
 //I have a form panel which contain grid panel (need it for my implementation)

var registerGrid = Ext.create ('Ext.form.Panel',{
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    id:'gridForm',
    title:'Registration<h2> ',
    frame : true,       
    bodyPadding: 5,
     layout: 'column',
     items: [{
         xtype: 'gridpanel',
            store: registerBaby,
         height: 300,          
         title:'Reistration Baby Data',            
         columns: [{
                       id     : 'fullName',
                       text   : 'Child Name',                  
                       dataIndex: 'fullName'
                   }],
                   dockedItems: [{  
                       xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',   
                       store: registerBaby,       //same store as grid  
                       dock: 'bottom',          
                       displayInfo: true    
                      }]                    
            }]
    });  
 });
```

Inspite of using the pagesize and autoload, all the record are displayed in Grid. plz help

Answer (score 0):

paging is supposed to be handled on the backend, if your request sends all data to the store, then all data will be shown.

Check the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging) : "Paging is typically handled on the server side (see exception below). The client sends parameters to the server side, which the server needs to interpret and then respond with the appropriate data."

You need to interpret the extra params the paging is sending in your request, like limit and start params, and return the data within those limits